# Why can I see beyond sRGB in CIE Chromatic Diagram

Tags: terminology, color, color-spaces, srgb

According to CIE 1931 color space chart, the sRGB gamut is what's inside the triangle:

[image]

As you can see from the diagram, blue is shown outside the sRGB gamut (at about 460 nm wavelength). Knowing that the monitor I'm currently using is pretty cheap (and it probably doesn't even support the full sRGB gamut, let along anything beyond it), how is it possible for me to see it? Is this diagram shifted somehow? If so, where can I get the "real" chromaticity diagram?

Comment: Typical computer monitors will have a larger gamut than sRGB. Also the chromaticity diagram that applies to your own vision may be 3 dimensional instead of 2 dimensional: http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20140905-the-women-with-super-human-vision. What may then happen is that in your 3 dimensional color space, the output of the monitor may be tilted while most other people will only see the two dimensional projection where the domain of the chromaticities is restricted to e.g. sRGB, this will then only appear to be stretched out at the boundary as mattdm points out.

Comment: _"Typical computer monitors will have a larger gamut than sRGB."_ I don't think that's the case, at least not for typical meanings of "typical".

Comment: `I don't think that's the case, at least not for typical meanings of "typical".` A lot displays actually have larger gamut than sRGB / Rec. 709, this is especially true with Rec. 2020 colourspace becoming standard (Rec. 2020 largely encompasses sRGB / Rec. 709).

Comment: @KelSolaar We're getting there. But those displays are still not "typical" — there's just a handful being made and they're all expensive, high-end products.

Comment: @mattdm Yes in regard to *Rec. 2020*, but pretty much all LCD / OLED displays nowadays have a larger gamut than *sRGB*, this is fairly easy to achieve as the primaries spds are much sharper than the ones from CRTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors on the diagram are just meant to give you an idea of the color space. You could say that the sRGB space is "shifted" to be larger in order to create the illustration.

Comment: You mean, the sRGB triangle was drawn smaller? Or the entire chromaticity diagram was drawn smaller?

Comment: I mean that the sRGB colors are "stretched" out of the triangle they actually belong in.

Comment: `The colors on the diagram are just meant to give you an idea of the color space.` This is not exact, depending the colourspace used to generate the diagram, you can entirely represent the colours of the chromaticity diagram. ACES2065-1 is such a colourspace, see my answer.

Comment: @KelSolaar It's hardly relevant that a colorspace which cannot be shown on any actual display exists. I stand by this answer as *completely* correct in the real world.

Comment: @mattdm I'm not sure to understand what you mean? Are you implying that a colourspace that cannot be displayed does not exist?

Comment: @KelSolaar What? No. Of course it is trivial to define a colorspace which maps outside of real vision.

Comment: @mattdm So what were you trying to say?

Comment: ... I'm saying what I said. I think you don't understand the question.

Comment: @mattdm Got the `[...] hardly relevant that a colorspace [...]` bit now.

I understand the question the OP asked, but as I stated in my answer and below comments, OP asked multiple questions while at same time making a wrong assumption about the colourspace represented by the diagram he linked.

Comment: Downvoting your answer as it doesn't give an accurate explanation on what is happening on a chromaticity diagram colours. It actually tricked @user1032613 into thinking the gamut of *sRGB* has been changed in order to display the colours which is not the case. Your following comment (while slightly better) is still not a good way of describing how the diagram has been generated and why one can still see colours beyond the *sRGB* gamut. For reference, I tracked how the linked one was generated: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CIE1931xy_blank.svg

Comment: @KelSolaar I didn't know this question is still active, thanks! Could you please elaborate on "tricked [me] into thinking the gamut of sRGB has been changed"? To my understanding, the picture I linked in the original question, every pixel of that picture, all fall inside sRGB, that's why I'm able to see it on a cheap monitor. Is that not correct?

Comment: @user1032613 Yes it is correct, the colours have been clipped to lie on *sRGB* gamut boundaries, then the diagram author did some creative adjustments (which are questionable). I gave some more details in my long answer below because I wanted to correct some wrong assumptions you had like the fact the depicted colourspace in your diagram is not *sRGB / Rec. 709* but *CIE RGB* which uses *E* as illuminant, etc...

Comment: @user1032613 Perhaps replace the diagram in your question with one which actually shows sRGB, addressing some of Kel's concerns?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a visualisation. The colours in the diagram do not represent the real colours of the noted wavelengths (what you see is dependent on the capabilities and calibration of your monitor anyway), but are chosen to give you an idea where the different colours rougly lie.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably complicated to reply accurately to your question without knowing which parameters have been used to generate the chromaticity diagram. However the following facts remain:

- Your linked chromaticity diagram colours have been altered / blurred to attenuate the discontinuities introduced by conversion from *CIE XYZ* tristimulus values to *sRGB / Rec. 709* colourspace.
- The represented *RGB* colourspace triangle is actually not *sRGB* colourspace but *CIE RGB* colourspace which is entirely different.
- If you were to depict accurately *sRGB / Rec. 709* colourspace and use it to generate the chromaticity diagram colours, all the colours outside the triangle would not be represented accurately and would have one or more negative component(s) needing to be normalised and clipped in order to be displayed which is the reason you see them in your linked diagram.
- It is entirely possible to represent the colours of the chromaticity diagram using a wide gamut colourspace such as ACES2065-1, they would not be displayed correctly though because no display exists that can represent such a colourspace.

Here is a normalised and clipped chromaticity diagram for *sRGB / Rec. 709* colourspace, rendered in *sRGB* colourspace:

[image: sRGB / Rec. 709]

The same as above but this time not normalised but clipped:

[image: sRGB / Rec. 709 - Unaltered]

And one representing the *ACES* encodings for reference:

[image: ACES Encodings]

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining what's wrong with my answer instead of just downvoting without any proper explanations. Considering the OP question is partially incorrect, I did provided relevant points.

Comment: I think you are entirely misunderstanding the question. There's no question that some colorspaces exist which encompass the entire color space chromaticity diagram. The question is: given that the diagram itself is actually shown in sRGB (or smaller!) on the original asker's monitor, why are there colors visible _outside_ of that triangle?

Comment: I think you are entirely misinterpreting my answer :)

I understood the question(s) properly (because there are actually multiple questions) and replied to them on each of my points, by first introducing the fact that the diagram has altered colours (so they are wrong), second correcting the fact it is not *sRGB* being represented, third stating the reason why you can see the colours (because they are clipped and altered), fourth (bonus) giving an alternative colourspace that can represent entirely the visible spectrum, fifth I provided an accurate chromaticity diagram.

Comment: I agree, Kel,  In particular this point "The represented RGB colourspace triangle is actually not sRGB colourspace but CIE RGB colourspace which is entirely different' is  correct. Describing the triangle as representing sRGB is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Completely independent of the colors that are put inside the chromaticity diagram, no monitor (and no printer either) based on three visible colors can ever display all the colors the diagram represents. The reason is simply: Visible colors have to be inside the "horseshoe", and whatever three (or even six) colors you choose, the polygon defined by these colors can never fill the whole horseshoe. (All colors that can be created by a device are inside the polygon that is defined by the device's primary colors)